# How can I create a pipeline for existing freestyle projects?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working for some time with jenkins freestyle projects.

Now I was looking for a solution to create a "pipeline" which execute multiple of these (parameterized) freestyle projects. Something like this:

```
// execute freestyle project A with parameter p1=a
// execute freestyle project B with parameter p2=b
if((A finished successfully) && (B finished successfully)){
    // execute project C with parameter p3=c
    if((C finished successfully) && p4 == "yes"){
        // execute project D with parameter p5=d 
    }
}
```

I found Jenkins Pipeline, but I'm not sure if this is the actual use case for a Jenkins Pipeline. Jenkins Pipeline looks more like an advaned freestyle project to me, not an "orchestrating" tool for existing projects.

So which plugin should I use for this need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely can do it using Jenkins pipeline

```
stage('triggering jobs') {
    build job: 'A', parameters: [string(name: 'p1', value: 'a')]
    build job: 'B', parameters: [string(name: 'p2', value: 'b')]
    build job: 'C', parameters: [string(name: 'p3', value: 'c')]
    if (p4 == 'yes') {
        build job: 'D', parameters: [string(name: 'p5', value: 'd')]
    }
}
```

You don't need to check explicitly result statuses of downstream jobs because the orchestration job will fail if one of them fails.
See [build step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job) for more information.