# Parametrize Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: parameters, jenkins-pipeline

How can I parametrize my jobs from the pipeline syntax?

I have the job:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMbri.png)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe2pV.png)

How can I apply ENV parameters to the jobs inside my pipeline scripts by the same ENV selection for the pipeline?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc28h.png)

So when I run my pipeline I want to select the parameter one time and apply this parameter for all the jobs inside my pipeline syntax

Comment: answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612656/how-can-i-create-a-pipeline-for-existing-freestyle-projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        string defaultValue: '', description: 'Name: ', name: 'NAME', trim: true
    }

    stages {
        stage('Printing parameters') {
            steps {
                script {
                    print("Hi, my name is ${env.NAME}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you say "apply this parameter for all the jobs inside my pipeline", I'm assuming you mean "all the stages inside my pipeline". Jenkins treats parameters as environment variables, so once they're filled, they can be read in all pipeline stages.

Best regards.

Comment: hey,
no, my syntax is:

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('First run') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    build '2_1_tlcg_ocit_crud'
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
And when I build the freestyle project 2_1_tlcg_ocit_crud that has also ENV parameter inside I want it to inherit the ENV from the pipeline

Comment: Oh sorry! Think I got it now. Unfortunatelly, Jenkins doesn't share environment variables amongst jobs, so you have to pass them when you call the `build` step, or through an artifact.

Comment: Please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62072625/jenkins-pipelines-trigger-one-after-another/62074305#62074305

Comment: Hey, yes that's what I need!
also, found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612656/how-can-i-create-a-pipeline-for-existing-freestyle-projects